# Scanner.Buffer - max value has no effect on custom Split?

Tags: go

To reduce the default 64k scanner buffer *(for microcomputer with low memory)*, I try to use this buffer and custom split functions:

```
scanner.Buffer(make([]byte, 5120), 64)
scanner.Split(Scan64Bytes)
```

Here I noticed that the second buffer argument "max" has no effect. If I instead insert e.g. **0**, **1**, **5120** or **bufio.MaxScanTokenSize**, I can' t see any difference.
Only the first argument "buf" has consequences. Is the capacity to small the scan is incomplete and if it's to large the B/op benchmem value increases.

From the doc:

> The maximum token size is the larger of max and cap(buf). If max <= cap(buf), Scan will use this buffer only and do no allocation.

I don't understand which is the correct max value. Can you maybe explain this to me, please?

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/aU-Wnv8pAGv)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func Scan64Bytes(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    if len(data) < 64 {
        return 0, data[0:], bufio.ErrFinalToken
    }
    return 64, data[0:64], nil
}

func main() {
    // improvised source of the same size:
    cmdstd := bytes.NewReader(make([]byte, 5120))
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdstd)

    // I guess 64 is the correct max arg:
    scanner.Buffer(make([]byte, 5120), 64)
    scanner.Split(Scan64Bytes)

    for i := 0; scanner.Scan(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\r\n", i, scanner.Bytes())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: The initial buffer and max size only effect the buffered memory used. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I have initialized the smallest possible buffer for the project, to save resources and 64 bytes are read per line/token. I'm completely unsure about the required "max" value. Maybe it's the translation... I'm just totally lost.

Comment: I don’t know what you expect when you start with a 5120 byte buffer, but want to somehow limit that to 64 bytes. Regardless of the buffer size the scanner behavior will be the same. Just finish writing the code and worry about optimizing memory usage later.

Comment: This means I could set the value right from the start to `scanner.Buffer(make([]byte, 5120), 5120)`? My microcomputer has only limited free memory and needs a swap for some tasks.

Comment: It makes no difference. The docs you quote say specifically that if max is less than or equal to the size of the buffer, then it won’t allocate more.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for your help and time. Now I have finally understood :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> max value has no effect on custom Split?

No, without split there is the same result. But this wouldn't be possible without split and ErrFinalToken:

```
//your reader/input
cmdstd := bytes.NewReader(make([]byte, 5120))

// your scanner buffer size
scanner.Buffer(make([]byte, 5120), 64)
```

The buffer size from the scanner should be larger. This is how I would set buf and max:

```
scanner.Buffer(make([]byte, 5121), 5120)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out that `scanner.Buffer` **must >** `bytes.NewReader` . And your helpful example with the "max" value.